# Visual Studio Code debugging: name a variable and cast it

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-code, void-pointers, vscode-debugger

1. How to give a custom name to a variable listed on watch list in debug mode of VisualStudio Code?
2. Is there a way to automatically cast variables to char* from pointer so that - if they contain text it will be visible for the user?

I use VSCode to debug large C program. 
When debugging, there are large structures like:

`type variable;`
where variable is a head of one directional list:

```
feature_type *variable->feature
char* variable->features->head->name // name of the 1st feature
feature_type *variable->features->head->next // 2nd feature, that has its own "name"
void* variable->features->head->a->b->c->value // value of a 1st feature.
```

The problem is, that variable value is very often (95%?) char*, and I'd like to see it as such, but now - for each element of the list I have to manually select it, and cast to (const char *). Its annoying as it feels that printing those variables - thou less professional - would be a lot faster.

[image: fragment of the code in VSCode]

```
(const char *) (((((type *)0x844430)->a).b).c).value // rewritten what was important on the picture that you might want to copy.
```

The second problem is that variables casted in such way all have same name, but differ only in the memory address (which means I have to remember which is which). Is there a way to give them a name?

Comment: Posting text as text rather than a picture is more useful in creating answers and searching.  Consider editing in as text.

Comment: I have written whole example in text, above. the picture is there to show how it looks like in the Debugger - as I cannot see a name of variable, just the ending (a->b->c-> value)

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the **code** not the IDE.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it..  Also,, please clarify what the code is trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm not asking for help in debugging or writing code. Code is what it is and for a project of this size rewriting core structure of data representation would be highly time-consuming.
I wrote my intentions clearly - I want to give a *name* to variables that are added to the watch list (because now they all look the same) and also automatically cast such variables to char* in order for the debugger to show me contents.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this while searching how to look at the values in memory in the watchlist. It looks like you can set the variable name in the gdb window, and use that name in the watchlist.

Debug Console:

```
-exec set $var_name = (const char *) (((((type *)0x844430)->a).b).c).value
```

Then in the watchlist you can just reference the convenience variable as `$var_name`

[image: VS Code Debugger]

Comment: But won't the addresses change after some period of time (or after re-set of the computer)?

Comment: Yea, it looks like you'd have to reset each run? Could probs look into setting up your gdbinit so it initializes each time its run, not sure if that gets executed through VS Code or not. 

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html